# How do I plot this data as a grouped barchart?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I would like to plot this data in R

```
item    response    Freq
count   -99         0.000
count   -88         0.000
count   -77         0.050
count   1           0.039
count   2           0.117
count   3           0.408
count   4           0.385
read    -99         0.011
read    -88         0.000
read    -77         0.117
...      ...        ...
```

the x axis should be item (so count, read etc., altogether 19 items), on the y axis should be the Frequencies for each response (so 1,2,3,4,-77,-88,-99). So this would be a "grouped" barchart essentially.

I am not able to plot this grouped bar chart using R. Until now, i tried it with:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(Data, aes(response, Freq*100, color = item)) +
  geom_point(size = 4) + geom_line(size = 1, aes(group = item)) + ggtitle("Items") + 
  ylab("Frequencies %") + xlab("responses") 


require(lattice)
barchart(Freq*100 ~ item, groups=response, Data, xlab="Items", ylab="Frequencies %")
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you *require* this to be done in `ggplot2`, or is base R also OK?

Comment: doesn´t need to be done with ggplot. the main thing is R

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(x=1, y=Freq, fill=factor(response))) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") +
  facet_grid(~item) +
  scale_fill_grey() +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

The `position="dodge"` aligns the bars side-by-side. The `facet_grid` uses a new plot for each "item" (i.e. each group that is indicated by the variable named "item"). The `scale_fill_grey()` applies grey colours to the bars and the `theme_bw()` removes the grey background.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dat <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="item    response    Freq
count   -99         0.000
count   -88         0.000
count   -77         0.050
count   1           0.039
count   2           0.117
count   3           0.408
count   4           0.385
read    -99         0.011
read    -88         0.000
read    -77         0.117")
```

Using `ggplot2`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(x=item, y=Freq, fill=factor(response))) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks! Its working but since I have 19 Items it is not usable like this. Besides I need it to be expressive in black and white...

Comment: Please elaborate on `it's not usable`.  What would you like to change to make it usable? Your requirement for grey scale was not in the question - we're not mind readers.

Comment: No, I know that. Just dont know how to express my thoughts, sorry :)
The black-white-grey graph is good. If I take all 19 Items in one plot, the bars are getting too slim. So I think I need to use several small plots and maybe it is possible to write "count" etc. upright.

Answer (score 0):

Try for black-white-grey graph:

```
barplot(with(ddf, tapply(Freq , list(response, item), mean)), beside=T, xlab="item", ylab="Freq")
```

[image]